# $list.RootFolder.Url empty

Tags: list, powershell

I get an empty url
when I try to retrieve the list root folder url.

I use these Powershell commands on a Sharepoint 2010 server.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://mywebsite"
$list = $web.lists["My Documents List"]
write-host $web.Url #returns my web url
write-host $list.RootFolder.Url # returns an empty string
```

What's wrong with them?

**Edit:**
with:

```
$list = $web.Lists.TryGetList("My Documents List")
```

I get (I ran it as administrator):

```
Exception calling "TryGetList" with "1" argument(s): "Access is denied. (Except
ion from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
At C:\temp\updatedtcomtit.ps1:6 char:30
+ $list = $web.Lists.TryGetList <<<< ("My Documents List")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Comment: Are you sure you have gotten the list? It could very well be null when you retrieve it

Comment: are you passing the Document Folder name or Document Library? your name telling me may be you putting the folder name

Comment: It's the library actually.I'll edit it. And to answer Robert, yes I retrievea null list but the name I pass is correct

Comment: It's the title right? Try `$web.Lists.TryGetList("My document list")` to get the list by title

Comment: Robert the title is right. I've just edited with TryGetList

Comment: My problem in the end was that I got the site with my AAM. With servername it works

Answer (score 0):

Url doesn't appear to be a property of the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-s/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder_members.aspx

There is a ServerRelativeUrl property which should help though.

Comment: Url just returns the internal name for the library.